# Using multiplied macro in array declaration

Tags: c, arrays, macros

I know the following is valid code:

```
#define SOMEMACRO 10
int arr[SOMEMACRO];
```

which would result as `int arr[10]`.

If I wanted to make an array 2x size of that (and still need the original macro elsewhere), is this valid code?

```
#define SOMEMACRO 10
int arr[2 * SOMEMACRO];
```

which would be `int arr[2 * 10]` after precompilation. Is this still considered as constant expression by the compiler?

After a quick look it seems to work, but is this defined behavior?

Comment: Yes, that's evaluated at compile time and used as a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this still considered as constant expression by the compiler?

Yes. That's the difference between a constant expression and a literal: a constant expression need not be a **single** literal, bit it can be any expression of which the value can be computed at compile time (i. e. a combination of literals or other constant expressions).

(Just for the sake of clarity: of course literals are still considered constant expressions.)

However, in C, the size of the array need not be a compile-time constant. C99 and C11 supports variable-length arrays (VLAs), so

```
size_t sz = // some size calculated at runtime;
int arr[sz];
```

is valid C as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work.MACRO will be placed as it is at compilation so `a[2*SOMEMACRO]` will become `a[2*10]` which is perfectly valid.

To check what is preprocessed you can use `cc -E foo.c` option

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use this expression. It will not result in UB.
Note that an array subcript may be an *integer expression*:

```
#define i  5 
#define j  4
int a[i+j*10] = 0;
```

The value of of subscript `i+j*10` will be calculated during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, as long as it a valid number it's a constant expression.
and if you say it worked then you know the compiler worked just fine with it.

as you know we can't do

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);
int arr[2 * x];
```

because that's no a constant number. but what you've written is a constant number, so you're good to go

Comment: i think second we can do with new compilers

Comment: "we can't do" - we can, do you happen to live before 1999?

Comment: This is valid in C99.